# Alignment of the TabBarControls in a TabSet

Tags: smartgwt

we're using smartGWT for our web application. An the main page is a tabset that shows different tabs. What I want to do is do a button to the tab set with the setTabBarControls method which then is alligned to the left instead to the right. So it would somewhat look like the current Firefox version.

Is there a possibility to change the allignment of the TabBarControls? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create something like the Firefox corner button, just use TabSet.addChild().  That will place the button at the upper left, and you can use setLeft/setTop to move it elsewhere.  If you want the control to appear to the left of the tabs, set a layoutStartMargin on the TabBar to leave space for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do I add a layoutStartMargin to the TabSet. I couldn't find any mehtod do to this, the API only allows this for classes of type Layout, where the TabSet is only Canvas.

Comment: Ok i found out how to add the layoutStartMargin to the TabBar. I found the SmartGWT Starter Guide with the chapter about customizing the style of SmartGWT's components. Works fine, thanks.